# Fragment not fill in layout when add it in java code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i have layout like below image :

[image]

and the below all button in layout is linear layout i will add myFragment into .

But when i put MyFragment to linear layout . it not show fill to linearlayout same like this :

[image]

how can i make fragment fill to layout ?

update here is xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fi"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFee00"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAttachA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnReplaceBwithA"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnReplaceBwithA"
    android:text="Attach A " />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRemoveB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnRemoveA"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:text="remove b" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRemoveA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="RemoveA" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnRemoveA"
    android:text="Add B" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAddB"
    android:text="add A" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnReplaceBwithA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnRemoveA"
    android:text="replace B with A" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDettachA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnReplaceBwithA"
    android:text="Dettach A" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnReplaceAwithB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnDettachA"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnDettachA"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnDettachA"
    android:text="replace A with B" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutforrepalce"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnDettachA"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is xml for fragment A

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#AA66CC"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="this is Fragment A"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: have you try height with match_parent

Comment: Its a problem with how your layout_height is set up for the layout your fragment is being inflated into. Its hard to say what exactly you need to do to fix it without seeing your XML for the layout-file.

Comment: i just update my code xml pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Odds are you are using wrap_content in your xml file.  Try using match_parent or fill_parent in android::layout_height.

Comment: every thing layout i set fill_parent or match_parent .but it not i will update xml file right now pls give me a solution